# How do I get this Python script to execute at the certain time?

Tags: python, bots, schedule, reddit, praw

I would like to get the script to execute at a certain time and date.

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent="UA goes here")
r.login("username", "password")
sub = r.get_subreddit("Subreddit name goes here")
sub.submit("Title goes here", text="Post text goes here")
```

I'm trying to create an auoposting thread bot for my subreddit. This single task of getting this script to run and execute properly has been a pain in the butt. I've tried opening the .py file with task scheduler, but sadly i've had no luck. Everyone i've asked has told me that I have to get familiar and pretty much learn python fully. I don't want to take 3 weeks to learn python, I want to autopost threads to my subreddit.

Comment: Windows Scheduled Tasks or Linux Cron Jobs...  Outside of that I'm not quite sure what the dealio is?  What problems have you encountered?

Comment: windows xp. I've saved the script as a .py file, then I used task schduler to open up the file but instead of opening it a black command box pops up for half a second and nothing happens...are there any task schduling applications I can download that are more user friendly.


P.S. the only time I can get this script to work is when i first input it into the IDLE (Python GUI).. Once i save it as a .py file and open it up again via the IDLE (python GUI) it doesn't work. it basically turns into a word document.

Comment: have you tried just opening a command prompt and executing the script or putting a pause in the script to see what is being output.  Also are you directly calling the script or passing in `python script.py` and setting up the environment properly

Comment: I've inputed the script into the command line and it worked successfully. Im opening the .py file directly from task schdeuler. I probably should have given up by now honestly. I've been going at this for more than a week.. haha

Answer (score 1):

Set up a Windows scheduled task. To cause the python routine to execute and then leave the window open so it's output can be seen by the user, use this as the task run:

```
cmd.exe /k "python C:/path/to/script.py"
```

`/k` causes the window to stay open.